# What solution is there to project google/bing layers to another EPSG (e.g. 3844)?

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver

I am using Geoserver and Openlayers. The Openlayers map has all the layers in EPSG:3844.
I need to overlay Google/Bing layers.
I am currently trying to do it with proj4js,  mapproxy.org as openlayers doesn't have reproject support for WMS.

Any solutions?

Comment: You need to do the opposite - reproject the EPSG:3844 to match the Google/Bing projection

Comment: I need the map in EPSG:3844, I don't need it in EPSG:3857.

Comment: The Map tiles are set from Google/Bing - each zoom level would need to be reprojected - that gets very heavy at zoom level 17 - Tile Coordinates - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/overlays#Tile_Layer_Overlays Google use http://spatialreference.org/ref/esri/54004/

Comment: Mapperz is right, if you want to use Google/Bing/Esri tiled layers, you need to project your data to the web mercator projection 102100. 102100 and 3857 are same projection.

Comment: I don't want to change the hypothesis: the map has to be in EPSG 3844. Your solution changes the hypothesis and that's not what I wanted.